# EventCallback - is it a func delegate?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

What does this mean?

```
 public EventCallback<Trail> OnSelected { get; set; }
```

Does this mean OnSelected  is a delegate (function paramter) that holds input parameter of type `Trail` and return parameter void?

Why is EventCallback used?

If I have to return a parameter of type string for this delegate how would this declaration look like?

will it look like ?

`public EventCallback<Trail, string> OnSelected { get; set; }`

Comment: A good, canonical answer to this question should be one that explain in historical terms of the Blazor development, why the EventCallback "delegate" was created, and what problems it tried to solve. In the past, we used the Action and the Func delegates and other constructs instead. There is an old and lengthy article in Github, written by the creator of the EventCallback "delegate", which explains the issues developers faced then, and the necessity of developing a new structure to solve this issues.

Comment: As to the title of your question: EventCallback is a CSharp struct that may produce a func delegate or an action delegate, depending on how you use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is a bound event handler delegate.

One of the most common scenarios for using `EventCallback` is to pass data from a child component to the parent component.

Here is a simple demo about how to pass the string value:

**child component**

```
<h3>TestChild</h3>

<input @onchange="UseEcb"/>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> RecoverRequest { get; set; }
        
    async Task UseEcb(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await RecoverRequest.InvokeAsync(e.Value.ToString());
    }
    
}
```

**parent component**

```
page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<h2>@result</h2>

<TestChild RecoverRequest="Test"></TestChild>

@code {
    

    [Parameter]
    public string result { get; set; }

    private void Test(string a)
    {
        result = "Child Component value is "+a;
    }
    
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> To answer your first three questions:

An EventCallback is a `readonly struct`.  It's a wrapper for a delegate that supports async behaviour through `EventCallbackWorkItem`.

It looks like this (extracted from the AspNetCore source code):

```
public readonly struct EventCallback<TValue> : IEventCallback
{
    public static readonly EventCallback<TValue> Empty = new EventCallback<TValue>(null, (Action)(() => { }));

    internal readonly MulticastDelegate? Delegate;
    internal readonly IHandleEvent? Receiver;

    public EventCallback(IHandleEvent? receiver, MulticastDelegate? @delegate)
    {
        Receiver = receiver;
        Delegate = @delegate;
    }

    public bool HasDelegate => Delegate != null;

    internal bool RequiresExplicitReceiver 
        => Receiver != null && !object.ReferenceEquals(Receiver, Delegate?.Target);

    public Task InvokeAsync(TValue? arg)
    {
        if (Receiver == null)
            return EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync<TValue?>(Delegate, arg);

        return Receiver.HandleEventAsync(new EventCallbackWorkItem(Delegate), arg);
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync() => InvokeAsync(default!);

    internal EventCallback AsUntyped()
        => new EventCallback(Receiver ?? Delegate?.Target as IHandleEvent, Delegate);

    object? IEventCallback.UnpackForRenderTree()
        => return RequiresExplicitReceiver ? (object)AsUntyped() : Delegate;
}
```

You can see the above source code and other related code here  - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/EventCallback.cs

> To answer your last two questions:

In your example `Trail` is what you return.

You would call an EventCallback that returns a string like this in the component:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="@this.enteredValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.HandleSelect>Set Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick=this.SetSelect>Set Me To Hello</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="p-2 m-2 bg-dark text-white">
    Value: @this.Value
</div>
@code {
    private string enteredValue = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnSelected { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private async Task SetSelect()
    {
        await OnSelected.InvokeAsync("Hello");
    }

    private async Task HandleSelect()
    {
        await OnSelected.InvokeAsync(enteredValue);
    }
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
@page "/"
<h2>Test Page</h2>
<MyComponent Value=@this.textValue OnSelected=this.HandleValueChanged />

@code {
    private string textValue = string.Empty;

    private async Task HandleValueChanged(string value)
    {
        // Emulate some async activity like getting data
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.textValue = value;
    }
}
```

If you want to return more complex data, create a struct or record to return.

For general usage see the MS-Docs article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#eventcallback.